# neovim: Error detected while processing function <SNR>29_on_window_changed[22]..<SNR>29_ini t[29]..<SNR>29_on_colorscheme_changed:

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-airline

I recently was looking into nvim, and was Downloading the vim-airline-gruvbox-git from the AUR, which resulted in this error, even after multiple tries of uninstalling the package/plugins and reinstalling everything:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>29_on_window_changed[22]..<SNR>29_init[29]..<SNR>29_on_colorscheme_changed:
line    4:
E117: Unknown function: airline#init#gui_mode
```

And I sadly have no Idea what I can take from this and how I should go about fixing it.

I know I should of looked if there was a github for this and added it to my configs, but here I am.

Edit: I resolved it by deleting some Folders named nvim, looked if it worked, maybe reinstalling here and there. Sorry for not remembering what Folders I deleted, but if you make this exact mistake, a probably cleaner solution is in the Comments (thanks TornaxO7).

Comment: "but here I am" well, that's the wrong place. Issue trackers exist for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look into its [`PKGBUILD`](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=vim-airline-gruvbox-git):

```
# ...
url="https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox"
# ...
source=("$pkgname::git+https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox.git")
# ...
```

it looks like that it's actually just installing the [`gruvbox`](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox) (this is the link from `url` in the PKGBUILD!) theme for airline:

```
install -Dm755 ${srcdir}/${pkgname}/autoload/airline/themes/gruvbox.vim ${pkgdir}/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/airline/themes/gruvbox.vim
```

but it does not install [`vim-airline`](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) itself. So all you need to do is installing [`vim-airline`](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) as well.

Comment: I already hat airline installed via Packer.nvim, but I guess you mean the aur package? idk

Regardless, I deleted some Folders who where named nvim, looked if it helped, reinstalled everything, and it works. That day was kind of a blurr (I was very frustrated), but it works flawlessly now ahaha. Even though I brute forced it in the end, thank you for replying!